# Adding a shortcode for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to add a shortcode in WordPress. This is my code. I am using Elementor and the Hello Elementor theme. Not sure what I am doing wrong. No error message. It won't display on the front end.

```php
function homeShortCode(){
    $string = '<script async data-uid="36f126fae8" src="//hypnotherapywithmiriam.ck.page/36f126fae8/index.js"></script>';
    return $string;
}

add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'homeShortCode');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
  function homeShortCode(){
    echo '<script async data-uid="36f126fae8" 
    src="//hypnotherapywithmiriam.ck.page/36f126fae8/index.js"></script>';
    
}

 add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'homeShortCode');
```